# WinLockDLL.dll functions in Windows7

Tags: winapi, dll, windows-7, dllimport

I'm running an app for testing students, which prevents them from doing anything but the test.

Naturally, the app blocks them from closing it, and blocks them from running the task manager (among other things):

```
[DllImport("WinLockDLL.dll")]
private static extern int CtrlAltDel_Enable_Disable(bool bEnableDisable);
private void Restrict(bool enabled)
{
    CtrlAltDel_Enable_Disable(enabled);
}
```

The dll contains other functions I use, such as hiding the taskbar and the desktop.

Until recently, the students all had WindowsXP, and it worked.
Recently the students have all upgraded to Windows7, and it stopped working.

During debugging, I've found that Windows7 simply doesn't HAVE WinLockDLL.dll, so I copied the dll to one of the W7 computers and gave the app a try.

This time it found the dll and raised no errors, but the function simply had no effect.

So, does anyone know of an alternative in Windows7?

The closest thing I found was [this](http://www.indigorose.com/forums/threads/29930-Useful-free-DLL-%28WinLock-DLL%29), in which someone posted that:

> All the functions you used in the example crash on Windows 7 unless you change the call to DLL_CALL_STDCALL

"Calling STDCALL" doesn't help, since that is exactly what `DllImport` **does** by default.

I've read of alternatives for blocking ctrl-alt-delete, such as canceling the ctrl key or blocking the taskmanager via registry or GPO, but I much prefer a simply alternative for WinLockDLL.dll, which contains several functions I use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a standard Windows DLL.  Sure, don't expect it to work on later versions of Windows.  The only supported way to disable Ctrl+Alt+Del is through the group policy editor.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks; I got some answers there. They didn't exactly solved the problem, but they definitely shed some light on the subject (it doesn't look like there **will** be a solution in the end...).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that finds this in the future. I am creating a library to replace WinLock.dll for Windows 7. The source can be found here.

[Win7Lock Github](https://github.com/dprice809/Win7Lock#win7lock)